# android HorizontalScrollView layout component direction

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

i have HorizontalScrollView containing horizontal linear layout when i am adding new button to the horizontal linear layout the buttons added beside each others from left to right and when exceeding the width of the screen the new added buttons will not be visible on the screen but a horizontal scroll will appear to scroll to right 
[image]

i want to make the direction of adding new button to the horizontal linear layout from right to left not from left to right .
[image]

Comment: how are you adding the buttons?, can you show us the code?

Answer (score 2):

When you use:

```
myLinearLayout.addView(myButton);
```

it adds them one after the other.
But if you use

```
myLinearLayout.addView(myButton, 0);
```

it adds `myButton` before the first item in the LinearLayout.

In addition to the above code, if you'd like to have your HorizontalScrollView to start from the right side, you can use the following code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
    }
}, 100L);
```

Answer (score 1):

i do this. its work API above 8 :

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrool"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytAll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this by simply using relative layout and adding new button with property

`android:layout_toLeftOf=""`